# CSS-Image border glow when hover with individual color

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like to ask how should I apply different colour glow to an image border when a user hover over? like say that in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcsjpcbb/2/) file, I have a green thumb and a red thumb. I want each image border to glow according to the colour of the image, or any colour that I specify. How should I achieve that?

PS** For example purposes the image are converted to base64 in the JSFiddle.

This is how I do in my CSS

```
img{
    width: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

img:hover{
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: i don't get it ! is that what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/jcsjpcbb/4/

Comment: There is no way for HTML/CSS to determine the main color of the image displayed. If you know the predominant color of each image, give them class names accordingly and write the related CSS.

Comment: I think @Paul has my answer... thanks Paul.... I managed to accomplish it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand your question then here is an example [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ilqnb)

```
img{
    width: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
   /* border:1px solid #fff;*/
  margin-right: 20px;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
}
img:last-of-type:hover{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(232, 0, 0, 0.67);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(232, 0, 0, 0.67);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(232, 0, 0, 0.67);
}
```

Comment: @AlexWilson Good answer but there is also support for Opera webbrowser (also back in 2014) with the "vendor extension or prefix": `-o-` for example: `-o-box-shadow`,  `-o-border-radius` more information can be found [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/css/o-vendor/).. I hope this comment is helpful to people who want to support more browsers.. NOTE: Always add the Vendor extensions before the default/at the end  in your code, for example: `box-shadow should be after the last  vendor extension as is perfectly written in Alex Wilson's code, good job

Answer (score 6):

As written in the comment, there is no way for HTML/CSS to determine the main color of the image displayed. If you know the predominant color of each image, give them class names accordingly and write the related CSS.

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcsjpcbb/11/)** for a simple version.

```
img.green:hover{
  border-color: #66afe9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,255,0, 0.6);
}
img.red:hover{
  border-color: #66afe9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 box-shadow: inset 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
```

to:

```
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/jcsjpcbb/10/)

[box-shadow Syntax:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```
Formal syntax: none | [inset? && [ <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur-radius>? <spread-radius>? <color>? ] ]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Box shadow also worked for,

```
img:hover{ box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }
```

If you want to more style in css

http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

or use your custom image like this

```
img:hover{background:url('http://www.addglitter.com/link-sparkle.gif');
```